# Putting twig generates HTMl into a JS variable

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I'm generating HTML code such as this

```
<li class="myclass"><p>bla bla</p><p> bla bla</p></li>
```

with a twig macro. I'd like to use this code with JS Jquery to append it somewhere, like this:

```
$('#myid').append('{{ my_macro() }}');
```

TWIG seems to be generated before JS and messing up my code

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal


$('#COA_Table').append('
```

Is that possible somehow or should I just create an hidden element somewhere in my page and append it by copying it ?

Comment: *like this* Is it the actual code you use?

Comment: forgot the ; but moretheless yes

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code please? I don't see any problem with the current one.

Comment: It seems strange to me that `$('#myid')` can transform into `$('#COA_TABLE')` out of nowhere. Are you sure you show us the correct lines of code? Besides that, can you give the code of `my_macro()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you get this error, because your macro generates line breaks.

try 1st:

```
{% macro my_macro(...) %}
{% spaceless %}
    ...
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

try 2nd :

```
$('#myid').append('{{ my_macro()|e('js') }}');
```

Comment: you are correct, I had many line breaks. I did otherwise for this matter but it's good to know that it's doable. Thanks